# How to align two spans together ?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems aligning two spans together. The second span starts slightly lower than the first one which is causing a mis-alignment of the spans.

Essentially I'm trying to align .cbtnSymbol and .cbtnLabel together so that they are starting at the same height.

Here is a testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/DwGEa/

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/DwGEa/19/

Just add `line-height: 30px; vertical-align:middle;` to `.cbtnLabel`

Answer (score 1):

Try to `float` the `span`-s - http://jsfiddle.net/DwGEa/4/

Comment: hi thanks for your response, is that the best way ? i thought inline-block with a height will get them lined up... but it didnt.

Answer (score 0):

Adding line-height and vertical-align seems to help, but I'm not 100% sure what final result you are after.

```
<div class="cmenu">
        <div class="cbtn add"><span class="cbtnSymbol">+</span><span class="cbtnLabel" style="line-height: 20px; vertical-align: top;">Add</span></div>
        <div class="cbtn add"><span class="cbtnSymbol">-</span><span class="cbtnLabel" style="line-height: 20px; vertical-align: top;">Delete</span></div>
</div>
```

Here's the modified jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DwGEa/11/

Answer (score 0):

Add the last four CSS properties additionally to your label tag CSS

```
.cbtnLabel {
     padding: 0 0 0 10px;
     font-size: 8px;
     height: 30px;
     display: inline-block;
     display: -moz-inline-stack;
     vertical-align:top;
     zoom: 1;
     *display: inline;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you will feel about this, but it looks like you already have your divs setup as a table.  So what about trying something like this:

```
<table class="cmenu">
    <tr class="cbtn add">
        <td class="cbtnSymbol">+</td>
        <td class="cbtnLabel">Add</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cbtn add">
        <td class="cbtnSymbol">-</td>
        <td class="cbtnLabel">Delete</td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

By doing this, you can get rid of some CSS for simplicity. (example: you won't need display:inline-block anymore)

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/DwGEa/37/